# Unable to read input using scanf()

Tags: c++

I am trying to run the following simple code to check if `scanf()` is working.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num=0;
    scanf("%d",&num);//Scanf not working
    printf("The number is %d",num);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it gives me an output of zero even though I enter some value for the variable 'num'.

For further clarification, I just installed turbo c++ in my new laptop. Is this causing some problem?

Comment: Your code works for me. Looks like C code though, in C++ it'd be better to use the facilities in `<iostream>`.

Comment: *For further clarification I just installed turbo c++ in my new laptop* -- Why waste time installing a compiler from 25 years ago?

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of items successfully scanned. You should check that return value, eg: `if (scanf("%d",&num) == 1) { printf("The number is %d",num); } else { printf("You did not enter a valid number"); }`

Comment: Be aware that C11 (or C99) and C++11 (or C++14) are different programming languages. There is no point in learning in 2017 a C++ dialect older than C++11. See  http://stroustrup.com/Programming/ And TurboC++ is not compliant with C++11 standard (it is a buggy, obsolete compiler that you need to scrap). So install some *recent* version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) (both are C++11 or C++14 compliant & C99 or C11 free software compilers). Better yet, install some Linux distribution on your new laptop. It is developer friendly (& made of free software).

Comment: What is your Input, what is the Output?

Comment: Input was 5 but it prints 0.

Comment: I run your code and it's working in Visual Studio 2013.